# variable undefined evaluating a coffeescript string

Tags: coffeescript

The following works from the coffeescript REPL but it doesn't work if I put it in a file and run it. It says that "a is not defined".

```
Coffee = require 'coffee-script'
a = {b: 1}
console.log Coffee.eval('a.b')
```

Any ideas how to get this to work as a script? I couldn't find any documentation on `.eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around at the [source code](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/master/src/coffee-script.coffee#L144), it appears we can use a `sandbox` option to set the context. This works:

```
Coffee = require 'coffee-script'
a = {b: 1}
console.log Coffee.eval('a.b', {sandbox:{a}})
```